Detect hand-checked boxes in a pdf document with GPT-4o
i am working on a open ai assistant which function is to validate a series of contracts based on how many checkboxes are checked.
However, it seems difficult to the assistant to do this task.
I have been trying two options:

Uploading it as a scanned pdf (unselectable words) and making the assistant recognize the text by OCR. This sometimes work, but with very low percentage of success.
Uploading the pdf as it is. With this, the assitant is capable of getting all the text and data, but it cannot detect the checkboxes.
Do you happen to know any possibility, or combination with other technologies that can help me solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.


This can be done without using an AI model like GPT-4o. I think you'd be better off using traditional OCR methods (OpenCV, Adobe, etc.) to scan for checkboxes, and then counting them with some fairly simple code.

Well, actually the assistant have a long document of rules, which determines if the contract is valid or not. Some of this rules are something like "if the section 14a is checked, you have to fill the 14c" or stuff like that, so i thought that the gpt4o could work fine analyzing those rules . Do you think it would be possible to combine OpenCv or Adobe with this rules, or maybe with gpt4o itself?

Now it makes more sense why you would want to use an LLM like GPT-4o; the different contract rules will probably make your documents very hard to parse. While I think you could use different OCR tools along with an LLM, the logic would become very complex, and in my experience, LLMs aren't great at answering many follow-ups with lots of context. Your best bet would probably be to just upload the entire document to GPT4-o and ask it specific questions.

I shoulda also mention that LLMs are very prone to hallucination, and are often wrong: especially with long, complex, and sometimes poorly scanned documents like contracts. You should really consider whether you want to risk many wrong answers when dealing with responses from the LLM.

@KJ I have both of them, hand filled and searchable PDFs. Looking at what you said, i think we are gonna stick to searchables ones only and make the users fill it on the web.
I didnt get the lowercase unique word part, ¿what do you mean by /T or /V? ¿Are you still talking about the gpt assistant here? Thank you in advance

"if the section 14a is checked, you have to fill the 14c" sound like something you can code easily in Python, Java or any other language. No GPT needed. Sounds like you just need a good OCR. This is not a GPT task.
